# How to pass list in postman in GET request and get in GetMapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I send a list of id to controller using Postman like this

```
localhost:8090/test/customer?id=1,2
```

And Controller like this

```
@GetMapping
public List<Customer> getCustomerListById(Optional<List<Integer>> customerId){

return getCustomerByIdService.getCustomerById(customerId.get());

}
```

And my CustomerRepo like this

```
public interface CustomerRepo extends CrudRepository<Customer , Integer>{

   public List<Customer> findByCustomerIdIn(List<Integer> customerId);

}
```

But it get error like this

```
{
"timestamp": 1528884327211,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "java.util.NoSuchElementException",
"message": "No value present",
"path": "/test/customer"
}
```

Comment: what is the path of the api `getCustomerListById`?

Comment: no `path` for the `GetMapping`?

Comment: no mapping between id in query string and customerId in method argument.

Comment: He may add "/customer" mapping to controller. If he's trying to do it in a RESTful way he won't need additional path. @Hearen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like bellow:-

get:

```
localhost:8090/test/customer?id=1,2
```

Once you get the comma separated ids then you can split them and do what you need to do.

code:

```
@GetMapping("/test/customer/{id}")
public List<Customer> getCustomerListById(@PathVariable String id) List<String> id,
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your url the name of the  parameter is `customer` but in your controller method the parameter name is `customerId`,they are not the same

Answer (score 0):

Check your request by debugging on chrome.
When you deploy your app on browser, you will see network tab in Developer's tool.
From there pick your Get request and paste it to Postman